# VB.net Maskedtextbox crashes

Tags: vb.net

```
    If Val(CurrencyHolder.Text) > 0 AndAlso CurrencyHolder.Text < 10000 Then
```

I've got this one here but when I enter this: ( input on the masked box ***4*,**
[image: It crashes on input 4]

Error : InvaledCastException was unhandled

So why does it crashes on that input?
Whats a good way to fix it?

Comment: are you getting an `ItCrashedException` or something else?

Comment: it looks like the input is 4 . (4 space dot) and not 4. What mask are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use Val() on both side of that or else you're working with a string in the comparison. Of course you would have Option Strict off otherwise that wouldn't compile and with Option Strict off it appears that the input is not a valid double so ensure the input is correct as it appears to have a space between the 4 and the period.

Comment: Thanks for a response!

I am getting : InvaledCastException was unhandled

Comment: Damn. Thanks that helped!
And it's working! Much appriciated : -)